# how to exclude not null and include only null values for two different tables with same columns names

Tags: database, oracle

Can someone please help me how to exclude not null and include only null values for two different tables with same columns names?

```
TableA                               TableB
Sub_id  Track_no   Active_date        Sub_id  Track_no   Active_date
-------  -------- -----------         -------  -------- -----------
001          123     null             001          124     01/02/2013
001          124     null
001          125     null
```

Here I need to get the records `Track_no` where active_date is null and sub_id = 001, I must join two table because Active_date is available in tableB only.

Comment: please share your sample output also, it will really help to understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

I hope i got you right

```
select * from tableA a 
inner join tableB b
on a.sub_id = b.sub_id
and a.track_no = b.track_no
and a.active_date is null
```

Comment: with your solution i am getting only one record , 
001          124     01/02/2013,  but i want other records it must exclude if there is a date in tableB

Answer (score 0):

The following query shows the tableA data, but active_date is taken from tableB in case it is null in tableA.

```
select sub_id, 
       track_no, 
       coalesce(a.active_date,b.active_date) active_date, 
       a.active_date active_date_from_a, 
       b.active_date active_date_from_b
from   tableA a 
         left join tableB b
           on a.sub_id = b.sub_id
```